# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32 on ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

Cant figure out the problem with this any help? the code stops at this line. I forgot to mention that I have a primary key which increments by one each time a new record is added. In the database it is also an integer. i didnt add it to this code as i presumed it would add itself when all of these records were added. if that makes sense.

```
recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery,
```

I'm not sure what the problem is with this.

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim recordsAffected As String
Dim cmdstring As String = "INSERT House (TypeofHouse, NumberofRooms, Location, Cost, Information, Picture) Values(@TYPEOFHOUSE, @NUMBEROFROOMS, @LOCATION, @COST, @INFORMATION, @PICTURE)"

conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\House.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@TYPEOFHOUSE", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtType.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMBEROFROOMS", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtNumOfRooms.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LOCATION", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLocation.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@COST", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtCost.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@INFORMATION", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtInfo.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PICTURE", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLocation.Text

conn.Open()

recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
conn.Close()
```

Comment: Possibly because you have cmd.ExecuteNonQuery and not cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()?  I assume you meant to put in ();

Comment: VB.NET doesn't always care if you don't put parenthesis when calling a method without parameters

Comment: And please provide more detail- when you say the code "stops", what do you mean?  It throws an error?  If so, what is the error?

Comment: Gotcha, I jumped the gun and assumed it was C#.  My bad..

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried converting your text to integer first.

I.E change:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMBEROFROOMS", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtNumOfRooms.Text
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMBEROFROOMS", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtNumOfRooms.Text)
```

The same would go for all your other Integers.

Basically your telling your parameter what data type to expect; `SqlDbType.Int` in this case, so you need to convert your input data; `txtNumOfRooms.Text` in this case, to the type expected.

Comment: i tried changing it to the above code and im not getting the error Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid. I forgot to mention that I have a primary key which increments by one each time a new record is added. In the database it is also an integer. i didnt add it to this code as i presumed it would add itself when all of these records were added. if that makes sense.

Comment: Says to me that your string is empty...put a breakpoint at `cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn)` and inspect all of your textbox fields. one of them is empty.

Comment: If your key is set to `Auto increment` then you don't need to worry about adding it. To do this open the designer of your table. and in the properties set "Identity Specification" to "Yes"

Comment: Yes thats what i have done. ^. still throwing up the same error

Comment: you need to put a breakpoint in and inspect all of your textboxed. one of them is blank.

Comment: Also - if you're setting any of the values of these textboxes when the page loads, make sure you do the setting inside `If (Not IsPostback)` - else whatever you type will be overridden by the page loading

Comment: all of the textboxes are empty on load. the user has to input the information into them and click submit. all of the information i am entering is correct

Comment: Stop your site, then Right-click on your code at the cmd= part and choose "Breakpoint" and then "Insert Breakpoint" - then press F5 to restart the site. it will stop running when you hit that point. and you can then inspect the code.

Comment: it stops at the Line 41:         cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMBEROFROOMS", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtNumOfRooms.Text). Input string was not in a correct format. I entered 2 in this textbox

Comment: When debugging step through (F10) until the line before Line 41, then hover your mouse over `Text` of the `txtNumOfRooms.Text` and you will see what is actually in the field.

Comment: If, when doing that, you see an empty string as the text then your text is being cleared during postback. Are these boxes added dynamically? If so, they need to be added OUTSIDE of any `if(Not IsPostback)`

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the content of `txtNumOfRooms` and `txtCost` to an `int` first.

Any one of the function calls below will probably work if the text in the respective input fields actually is a number:

- `CInt(txtNumOfRooms.Text)`
- `Int32.Parse(txtNumOfRooms.Text)`
- `Convert.ToInt32(txtNumOfRooms.Text)`

But since you are working with user input, you'd better check if the input for any numeric value actually is numeric, before trying to convert:

```
If Not IsNumeric(txtNumOfRooms.Text) OrElse Not IsNumeric(txtCost.Text) Then
    Throw new InvalidOperationException("Trying to convert a string to an integer")  
End If

cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMBEROFROOMS", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtNumOfRooms.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@COST", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtCost.Text)
```

Comment: tried adding this, now im getting the error. Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown. I am entering numbers into the textbox so i dont understand why it is doing this.

Comment: Are you entering numbers into both *Number of Rooms* and *Cost*? And if you do, are they natural numbers (i.e. not containing . , etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You have two parameters of type Int, but you set a text string as value.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TYPEOFHOUSE", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtType.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMBEROFROOMS", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumOfRooms.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LOCATION", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLocation.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@COST", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtCost.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@INFORMATION", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtInfo.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PICTURE", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLocation.Text
```

also you could use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TYPEOFHOUSE", txtType.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMBEROFROOMS", Convert.ToInt32(txtNumOfRooms.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOCATION", txtLocation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COST", Convert.ToInt32(txtCost.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INFORMATION", txtInfo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PICTURE", txtLocation.Text)
```

Of course you need to be sure that these two textboxes contains an actual string that could be converted to int. Otherwise using CInt, Parse or Convert.ToInt32 raises an exception.
You could introduce a bit of error checking before filling the parameters collection using [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) as in the following example.

```
Dim numOfRooms as Integer
if Not Int32.TryParse(txtNumOfRooms.Text, numOfRooms) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Type a valid number")
    return
End If

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMBEROFROOMS", numOfRooms)
```

Comment: i added your code in and it works but without error but even if i put 10 into the textbox noofrooms it will go into the database as 0?

Comment: I have made a mistake on the TryParse test, I fix the answer now

Comment: TryParse will check if your textbox contains a valid integer without triggering an exception like CInt, Parse or Convert.ToInt32. If the value is correctly converted it returns true and the integer numOfRooms should be set to the converted value. Otherwise the return is false and you could emit an error message or, if zero is acceptable as numOfRooms continue and update the field with zero

Comment: its still telling me to type a valid number event tho i am

Comment: Do you have reloaded the page?

Comment: yes i have this code under a click event, when i click the submit this code executes.

Comment: No, I mean this page, I have added a Not in front of the TryParse test.

Comment: still the same, ill figure it out somehow thanks for the help anyway. atleast 0 is going in stops from an error happening

Comment: Perhaps you are reloading your page on the PostBack when you press the button. Something is wrong in your Page_Load? Do you have a [Not IsPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) in place when you initialize the page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert TextBox's Text value i.e. `string` into `Integer` value for the column which has `int` dataType, like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMBEROFROOMS", SqlDbType.Int).Value =CInt(txtNumOfRooms.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you preforming validation on the textbox to verify that the string is a valid int?